# Extending a class--how do I avoid having to create multiple classes?

Tags: java, android, class, inheritance, ioio

The question doesn't really make sense, but this should help explain it better.

I'm currently using the IOIO, and it works like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends CustomIOIOActivity {}
```

From there I can call classes I've made in CustomIOIOActivity, which extends Activity.

The problem I'm running into now is that I have to inherit classes different from just Activity. For example, FragmentActivity.

Is there a way for me to create a custom IOIO activity which I can use for when I extend Activity and FragmentActivity? I don't want to have to make two essentially identical classes, which is what I am doing right now--seems silly. I'm not very familiar with Java, perhaps this is easy to do.

Comment: have an eg of what u gus

Answer (score 0):

In Java you can't inherit class from more than one superclass. In order to achive your purpose, I would advise you to move all common logic to another class(`IOIOHolder`, for example), which would take an `Activity` parameter in constructor. Later you can create two different classes extending Activity and FragmentActivity, each containing an exemplar of `IOIOHolder` and using it for it's own tasks. By using this approach you can write IOIO code once and use it in any activity you want.